# Any ways to hide HTML code (no obfuscation)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, obfuscation

Recently I came across a site named (http://tomerlerner.com) which looked very cool to me.

Just to study how this has been made, I looked into the source code (view-source:http://tomerlerner.com/about).

But a few things crippled me up. Like, if you see the 'MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS' (commented part) there he has hidden the main content with some sort of pointers. And the java scripts which are also commented out at the bottom are working.

Can anyone tell what process he has followed and how to do it.

Comment: seems he's using angularJS and minified all the JS into one

Comment: Excuse me, "pointers"? "Java scripts"?

Comment: As @Grainier said, it looks like the author minified all the js files and put them in `<script src="js/min.min.js?ver=11"></script>`. It seems that the commented out js files are just for clarification (to know what files make up the minified js file).

Comment: @chiru, everybody here is not a "expert" like you to use "appropriate terms". There are some people who are amateur in coding and only uses relative terms to make people understand

Comment: @SouvikRoy Actually, I was only trying to get you to clarify what you mean. `Pointers` are a whole different (low-level) concept in programming, and I pointed out "Java scripts" since you're obviously talking about "JavaScript scripts". Java would be a completely different language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can hide the HTML source since the code is what the browser get as instructions from the server.

But you can minify and uglify your JS/HTML in such a way that they would look convoluted to human eyes. This effectively hides any meaningful variable and function names and would make it difficult for someone else to reproduce the code in a readable way. Google for minify and uglify - you will get tons of solutions for this purpose.

And there are some server side solutions too emerging. Thosecan process client side scripts and render the markup in the server side itself before sending to the front end.

[Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) is one such framework.